# hours and minutest to timestamp - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have hours and minutes in firebase format (can't change this): `2230`

I need to convert this to normal date, year, day and month are current time, only hour and minutes are specifed

```
var startDate = new Date();
```

I need to set date something like this:

```
startDate.setHours(myhours, myminutes, myday, 0);
```

Comment: So the day is always the current day ?

Comment: yes, also other options are current

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to create a new `Date`, then just update those values:

```js
const hours = 15; // 24-hour format, 0 = midnight, 15 = 3PM
const minutes = 45;
const d = new Date();
d.setHours(hours);
d.setMinutes(minutes);
d.setSeconds(0);
console.log(d);
```

This will give you a `Date` object with the current time (as defined by the client's computer), but with the hours and minutes set to what you specify, and seconds set to `0` (since having `15:45:58` is weird).

To convert the string to variables, just do this:

```js
const [, hours, minutes] = '2230'.match(/(\d{2})(\d{2})/).map(m => parseInt(m));
console.log(hours, minutes);
const d = new Date();
d.setHours(hours);
d.setMinutes(minutes);
d.setSeconds(0);
console.log(d);
```

Keep in mind that it will assume you are setting it based on GMT (timezone offset +0000). If you want it relative to your time, either change the date object (if you just need its values to match) or shift it by your timezone offset.

```js
const hour = 15;
const minute = 45;
const d = new Date();
d.setHours(hour - (d.getTimezoneOffset() / 60)); // adjust hour to local timezone
d.setMinutes(minute);
d.setSeconds(0);
console.log(d);
```

Comment: yes but.. I have hours and minutes in this format 2230 (22 is hour and 30 is min)

Comment: `2230/100|0  //hours` and `(''+2230).substr(2) //minutes`

Comment: `time = (""+received_time).match(/\d{2}/g).reduce((o, c) => ((o.hh) ? o.mm = +c : o.hh = +c, o), {});`

Comment: I updated my post. Also included some stuff about timezones if you have to deal with them.